# Pandas error: IndexError string index out of range

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to append a Dataframe to an existing excel sheet using the below code snippet but I have been tucked with the below error.

my_data

```
      Date      Time     Year   Month   Track   #   Dist   Betfair_Grade    Runners Win Trap
   25/09/2021   09:27   2021    Sep    Bulli    R2  472m    Mdn               8.00  2.00
   25/09/2021   09:47   2021    Sep    Bulli    R3  400m    Gr5               8.00  9.00
   25/09/2021   10:53   2021    Sep    Bulli    R6  472m    Gr5               7.00  5.00
   25/09/2021   13:12   2021    Sep    Canning  R4  520m    FFA               5.00  4.00
   25/09/2021   11:59   2021    Sep    Bulli    R9  400m    M1/2/3            6.00  8.00
   25/09/2021   12:25   2021    Sep    Bulli    R10 472m    Rest              6.00  1.00
   25/09/2021   01:32   2021    Sep    Richmond R8  324m    Gr3               8.00  2.00
   25/09/2021   01:49   2021    Sep    Richmond R9  324m    Gr5               8.00  1.00
   25/09/2021   02:07   2021    Sep    Richmond R10 324m    Gr5               8.00  2.00
   25/09/2021   02:02   2021    Sep    Sheppar  R8  450m    Gr5               8.00  3.00
```

my_function

```
import os
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

file = r"file_test.xlsx"
 
# create excel file
if os.path.isfile(file):  # if file already exists append to existing file
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)  # load workbook if already exists
    sheet = workbook['my_sheet_name']  # declare the active sheet 

    # append the dataframe results to the current excel file
    for row in dataframe_to_rows(final_output_df, header = False, index = False):
        sheet.append(row)
    workbook.save(file)  # save workbook
    workbook.close()  # close workbook
else:  # create the excel file if doesn't already exist
    with pd.ExcelWriter(path = file, engine = 'openpyxl') as writer:
        final_output_df.to_excel(writer, index = False, sheet_name = 'my_sheet_name')
```

I tried to experiment with the above code on a new DataFrame, I don't get any errors. I can't tell what exactly is wrong.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [2,3,4,5,6]})
```

I also checked the index for both columns.

```
df.index, RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
my_data.index, RangeIndex(start=0, stop=94, step=1)
```

Error traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-a6b187072154> in <module>
     13 
     14     # append the dataframe results to the current excel file
---> 15     for row in dataframe_to_rows(final_output_df, header = False, index = False):
     16         sheet.append(row)
     17     workbook.save(file)  # save workbook

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\dataframe.py in dataframe_to_rows(df, index, header)
     52 
     53     for idx, v in enumerate(df.index):
---> 54         row = [data[j][idx] for j in range(ncols)]
     55         if index:
     56             row = [v] + row

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\dataframe.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     52 
     53     for idx, v in enumerate(df.index):
---> 54         row = [data[j][idx] for j in range(ncols)]
     55         if index:
     56             row = [v] + row

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: would guess that one of your new rows is shorter than the shape[1] of "sheet" dataframe which causes pandas append to crash

Comment: @EzerK when I check  `my_data.info()` of the data frame, they don't appear to any missing value

Comment: What is `final_output_df`?  Where does this come from?  With no further information, all I can do is to guess that the problem is that despite its name `final_output_df` isn't a dataframe at all and is in fact a string.